# vb script for carriage return in label string over 50 character long

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser, vbscript

IN ArcGIS, what is the vbscript in the label expression box to build a label  which has the outcome that if the string is over 50 characters long then the  label should be formatted over 2 lines.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried, and detail what happens when you try it.  Which GIS software are you using?

Comment: If you are using ArcMap, are you open to using the Python Parser instead?  Whether it is available would depend on your version.

Comment: I'm open to using the Python Parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doable using the VBS label parser in ArcGIS,  although recommended you start looking at using the Python parser as VBA/VBS is being phased out of ArcGIS Products.

In the Label Expression dialog check the *Advanced* box, and then paste the code below.  Change `[Description]` to the fieldname you are wanting to label.

If you just want to split the text after the 50th character you can use the following, however it may split mid-word and ignores whether the second line is longer than 50 characters also.

```
Function FindLabel ([Description])
  If len([Description]) <= 50 Then
    FindLabel = [Description]
  Else
    FindLabel = left([Description], 50) & vbNewLine & mid([Description], 50)
  End If
End Function
```

The following splits the label every 50 characters, at the nearest space (so doesn't split words), and splits additional lines if they are also longer than 50 characters.

```
Function FindLabel ([Description])
  If len([Description]) <= 50 Then
    FindLabel = [Description]
  Else
    newString = ""
    subString = ""
    a = Split([Description])
    For Each x in a
      If subString = "" Then
        subString = x 
      Else  
        lenSubString = len(subString & " " & x)
        If lenSubString > 50 Then
          If newString = "" Then
            newString = subString
            subString = ""
          Else
            newLine = True
            newString = newString & vbNewLine & subString
            subString = ""
          End If
        Else
          newLine = False
          subString = subString & " " & x
        End If
      End If
    Next
    FindLabel = newString
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have an error message of "Carriage returns are not allowed in simple expressions"

Comment: @MarcB I've fixed my answer - In the Label Expression dialog check the Advanced box before pasting the code

Comment: Midavalo, I cannot thank you enough. It works, fantastic.

Answer (score 6):

This is why you want Python:

```py
def FindLabel ( [TEXT]):
  t= [TEXT] 
  return '%s\n%s' %(t[:50],t[50:])
```